# Trying to get data from Gravity Forms | Warning: Illegal string offset 'fields' in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get all values of a Gravity Form I made on a WordPress website. I'm using the function I saw on GF documentation:

```php
add_action('gform_after_submission', 'add_formulario', 10, 2);

function add_formulario($entry, $form){

    if (is_array($form['fields'])) {

        foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {

            $inputs = $field->get_entry_inputs();

            if (is_array($inputs)) {

                foreach ($inputs as $input) {

                    $value = rgar($entry, (string) $input['id']);

                    echo $value;
                }
            } else {
                $value = rgar($entry, (string) $field->id);

                echo "no se logró";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "nope";
    }
}
```

And it gives me this error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'fields' in...`

Also it prints "Nope".

I saw that it means that I'm trying to get an array but it's actually a string. But I don't know how to solve this

Comment: What is the actual content of `$form`?

Comment: Why do you check if `$form['fields']` is an array? it's not like that in the documentation you mentioned

Comment: "is an associative array containing the form settings, fields, notifications, confirmations, and other properties"

Comment: When in doubt of a variable, dump it out an inspect it using a function such as [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)